# ERROR: no valid index found for toast relation with Oid 2840

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with 3 partial indexes on same condition with different column combination. I decided to go with bloom indexes and create only 1 partial index covering all columns and drop existing indexes to offload my table. I did the same and then  dropped all partial indexes.

Later on, when I just ran select * query ,instead of query output - I got below message:

```
shiwangini_dev=# select * from mage m limit 2  ;
ERROR:  no valid index found for toast relation with Oid 2840
```

However, some of the queries (with where clause) which uses this bloom index are returning data. Any way to avoid these errors will be really helpful

Comment: That is data corruption. Restore from backup.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - if I again restore and do the same exercise: dropping indexes and recreating new one - I again get the same error. Even if, I run analyze on same table after dropping/disabling existing same indexes (expect primary key)- I get the same error

Comment: Perhaps the corruption is already in the backup? Try to `pg_dumpall` and restore into a new cluster and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It's not working. I can successfully restore backup and able to query table. Only when I drop existing indexes then only I get this error

Comment: `pg_dumpall` and restore to a new cluster.

Comment: You said you did restore it and could repeat the problem.  Was that from a physical backup, like pg_basebackup, or logical, like pg_dump?

Comment: it was a logical backup pg_dump